# Eigenfunction of wave vector

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, quantum-states, normalization

I am reading some book, where it is said that the eigenfunctions are given by
$$\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\Omega}} \mathrm{e}^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot {\mathbf{r}}}$$

First of all, can somebody explain to me, how to read this term $\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}\rangle$ and why it is eigenfunction? I am used to notation of $L|\psi\rangle = l|\psi\rangle$.

My second question is how to get this formula? I started with eigenfunction for momentum
$$\mathbf{p}|\psi\rangle = p|\psi\rangle \\ -i\hbar \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}r}|\psi\rangle = p|\psi\rangle\\ \frac{\text{d}|\psi\rangle}{|\psi\rangle} = \frac{i}{\hbar}p \text{d}r$$

So as a result I get
$$|\psi\rangle = A\exp\left(\frac{i}{\hbar}p\cdot r\right).$$

First of all, I tried to use the relation $\mathbf{p} = \hbar \mathbf{k}$, and get
$$|\psi\rangle = A\exp\left(i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}\right)$$

But how should I normalize it? Is the integral equal to Dirac delta $\delta(\mathbf{k}-\mathbf{k}'$)? And is there any connection between my $|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle \mathbf{r}|\mathbf{k}\rangle$?

Comment: It is common in Dirac notation to label or enumerate the eigenstates of a self-adjoint operator with their respective eigenvalues. In  the case of the momentum operator: $  P |p\rangle  = p |p\rangle$. So in this sense $|\psi\rangle = |p\rangle$ in your case. As a last point, usually $\langle x|\psi\rangle \equiv \psi(x)$ denotes the wave function (in pos. space). IMO, the equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}r} |\psi\rangle = \ldots $ does not make much sense.

Comment: Thank you, but why do you think it does not make much sense?

Comment: Take a look at the given answer; you have to apply $\langle x|$ from the left. In other words, the momentum operator acts as a differential operator in position representation.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenfunctions of the momentum operator $\hat{p}$ or $\hat{k}$ as you also call it are $|k\rangle$ with
$$
\hat{p}|k\rangle = p |k\rangle
$$
By applying the bra of the position $\langle r|$ you get the position representation of a wavefunction $|\psi\rangle$ i.e. $\psi(x) = \langle r | \psi\rangle$. Therefore $\langle r | k\rangle \propto e^{i \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$ is the position representation of the eigenfunctions of the momentum operator.

Note that a plane wave $\psi(x) = e^{ikx}$ is itself not normalizable. This is results from Fourier theory or the Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle, because this wavefunction has a definite momentum $p$ so $\Delta p = 0$. To still be able to satisfy HUP you need $\Delta x = \infty$.

Comment: You might consider to address the question regarding the normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You notation is very confused. If $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat p$ expression
$$
\hat p|\psi\rangle = -i\hbar \partial_r |\psi\rangle
$$
cannot make sense as $|\psi\rangle$ is an element of the abstract Hilbert  space and knows nothing of $r$. You are confusing the abstract state vector $|\psi\rangle$ with its components in the position basis $\psi(r)\equiv  \langle r|\psi\rangle$. Here $|r\rangle$ are the eigenstates of $\hat r$:
$$
\hat r|r\rangle=r|r\rangle.
$$
It is the *components* of $|\psi\rangle$ that compose  the wavefunction.
The correct expression for the action of the momentum  operator is
$$
\langle r|\hat p| \psi\rangle = -i\hbar \partial_r   \langle r| \psi\rangle 
$$
which shows the action of the operator on the *wavefunction* in the position basis $\psi(r) = \langle r|\psi\rangle$. It is the wavefunction that takes the form
$$
\psi(r)\equiv \langle r|\psi\rangle= e^{ipr/\hbar}.
$$

Comment: Thank you, so my problem was confusing notation and I have to study more about representations. Thank you!